# MySQL: generate list of users who have purchased only a specific product

Tags: mysql

From a ecommerce database,  I need to identify the users who have purchased a specific product, and that product only. Users who have purchased that product and other products are excluded.

In the orders table, each row is unique to the product purchased.

```
user_id | order_id | product_id
20      | 01       | 65
20      | 01       | 68
21      | 02       | 68
22      | 03       | 68
21      | 04       | 65
```

In the example above, product 68 is the target product, and user 22 would be included in the list.

Orders including other products, even if 68 were also included in one, would cause the user to be excluded. An additional order of only 68 would not exclude the user.

Part two would be to match that user id to an email address in a second table, where email_address and user_id are columns per user row. How can I generate a list of email addresses matching the first condition?

I can do this in multiple steps via PHP, but I'd like to use this problem to get a better idea of how I could leverage SQL.

Comment: the matching for the email is just a simple join between the two tables on the user_id. Look for mysql JOIN and you will find tons of examples

Comment: If user22 took the same product_id in 2 or more orders will it be a match ?

Comment: Is your requirement specific to within a single order? If the customer ordered only the single product within one order, but also ordered a different product (or products) in another order should the customer be excluded, or not? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Deduction's fine, but why not mention the specific product of which you're thinking. Also, some evidence of effort would be appreciated. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - also, unless multiple users are somehow able  share aspects of a single order, your schema is not normalized.

Comment: Please edit your question, taking on board all the points raised to date.

Comment: i would say that your question implicitly contradicts your latest comment.

Comment: "Multiple orders, even if 68 were included in one, would be excluded." ....  "Purchasing product 68 a second time (but no other products) would still make that user a valid match" . So the first statement should really be "Finding an Order for a user which includes other products, even if 68 were also included in the same order, would cause the user to be excluded.". Is that right? Otherwise it's ambiguous, if not downright contradictory. And don't forget according to your question you're trying to return _users_ here, not orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your tables are named `users` and `orders`, the query below will:

1. Find all user ids that have only ordered a single product.
2. Find all distinct user ids that have ordered product_id 68 and who were members of the result from step 1.
3. Join the user ids from step 2 with the users table to get the email addresses.

Setup:

```
create table users (
  user_id int primary key,
  email_address varchar(100)
);

create table orders (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  user_id int,
  order_id int,
  product_id int
);

insert into users (user_id, email_address) values
  (20, 'twenty@email.com'),
  (21, 'twentyone@email.com'),
  (22, 'twentytwo@email.com');

insert into orders (user_id, order_id, product_id) values
  (20, 1, 65),
  (20, 1, 68),
  (21, 2, 68),
  (22, 3, 68),
  (21, 4, 65);
```

Query:

```
select email_address
from users
join (
    select distinct user_id
    from orders
    where product_id = 68 and user_id in (
        select user_id
        from orders
        group by user_id
        having count(distinct product_id) = 1
    )
) user_ids on user_ids.user_id = users.user_id;
```

Result:

```
twentytwo@email.com
```

Try it out: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c4590/1/0)